# How to use iwlist to scan hidden ssid?

Tags: linux, wifi

Should I configure some wireless settings (use commands on linux) so that "iwlist wlan0 scan" can list hidden APs if they exist? Or iwlist always reports hidden APs?

(I don't want to use wpa_supplicant to do AP scanning.)

Answer (score 2):

Commenting on a pretty old post but just came across this question and I don't believe `iwlist` scans for hidden APs. Remember the AP name is not broadcasted at all so there is no way for `iwlist` to magically find the name.

Instead, you have to pass the name of the AP during your scan. I.e you have to actively probe for that hidden network.

So your command should look something like this:

```
iwlist <my_wireless_interface> scan essid <my_fancy_essid>
```

Although I don't know how to scan for multiple hidden `essid`s in a single scan, this should detect a single hidden SSID.

> I have to mention this -- Hidden SSID does NOT add security at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think iwlist will show hidden non broadcasted SSIDs as well.
But to be sure you can test that by hiding your AP's SSID and test it (best way to be sure).

Answer (score 0):

```
iwlist <you_interface_name> scanning essid <your_hiddden_ssid>
```

will do the trick

otherwise iwlist shows hidden ssids with empty ESSID
e.g.: `ESSID:""`
than you have to match by the Address-Field, which holds the MAC
of the Station/Router.